# I have an integer in my database. I'm tryingto get the right column

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I have an integer in my database and I'm trying to get the right column to display the rest of the db

This is how I ask for it in Android studio

```
public class SeeorderRequest extends StringRequest {
    private static String SEEORDER_REQUEST_URL="http:Seeorder.php";
    private Map<String, String> params;

    public SeeorderRequest(String ordernum, Response.Listener<String> listener){
        super(Method.POST, SEEORDER_REQUEST_URL, listener,null);
        params= new HashMap<>();
        params.put("ordernum",ordernum);

    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;
    }
```

This is my php code

```
<?php


// array for JSON response
$response = array();
define('DB_USER', ""); // db user
define('DB_PASSWORD', ""); // db password (mention your db password here)
define('DB_DATABASE', ""); // database name
define('DB_SERVER', ""); // db server
// array for JSON response



 $conn = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);

// check for post data
if (isset($_GET["ordernum"])) {
    $id = $_GET['ordernum'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM orden WHERE orderid = $id";
$result = $conn->query($sql) or die (mysqli_connect_error());



    if (!empty($result)) {
        // check for empty result
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

            $result = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

            $orden = array();
            $orden["ordernum"] = $result["orderid"];
            $orden["pilotname"] = $result["pilotname"];
            $orden["pilotcash"] = $result["pilotcash"];
            $orden["date"] = $result["date"];
            $orden["hoobsstart"] = $result["hoobsstart"];
            $orden["hoobsend"] = $result["hoobsend"];
            $orden["watchtime"] = $result["watchtime"];         
            $orden["hoobstime"] = $result["hoobstime"];
            $orden["gas"] = $result["gas"];
            $orden["liter"] = $result["liters"];            
            $orden["repairname"] = $result["repairname"];
            $orden["repaircost"] = $result["repaircost"];
            $orden["travelexpense"] = $result["patient_email"];
            $orden["othername1"] = $result["othername1"];
            $orden["othercost1"] = $result["othercost1"];

            // success
            $response["success"] = 1;

            // user node
            $response["myorder"] = array();

            array_push($response["myorder"], $orden);

            // echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // no product found
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "No product found";

            // echo no users JSON
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    } else {
        // no product found
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No product found";

        // echo no users JSON
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

The problem is that in my db the value for order id is an auto increment int so I can't access it with this code, and the `hashmap` from android only accepts Strings.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: why can't you access it? you can still use auto_inc columns like any other column. they just have special semantics on record creation. `where auto_inc_field = $id` is perfectly valid.

Comment: So i should use where auto_inc_field = $id instead of WHERE orderid = $id" even if $id is a string value?

Comment: @MarcB i get this error b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in
<b>/home/a2521927/public_html/androidphp/Seeorder.php</b> on line
<b>24</b>

Comment: @tadman Any good tutorials on parameterized queries and bind_ param you know off for begginers? whenever i post a question ypou always put that warning XD

Comment: so where's line 24 in there? and note that you're vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and checking formysql errors wrong. `mysqli_connect_error()` is for errors caused by mysqli_connect() and cannot EVER report on errors caused by mysqli_query().

Comment: There's not much to it, the documentation has some good examples. Give it a shot and see how it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i fixed it the problem was this line :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM orden WHERE orderid = "$id";
```

it should be

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM orden WHERE orderid = $id";
```

and this line

```
if (isset($_GET["ordernum"])) {
    $id = $_GET['ordernum'];
```

its should be

```
if (isset($_POST["ordernum"])) {
    $id = $_POST['ordernum'];
```

Comment: `WHERE orderid=?` and later `bind_param('i', $_POST['ordernum'])` to bind data.